# Copying the files from one server to another server getting NTFS error

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am using one batch file to copy files from one server to another server. That batch file run fine when I run it manually, but I run the same batch file using task scheduler am getting below error.

> ```
> ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Source
>  \\Server ame\c$\ProgramData\DStt\
> Access is denied.
> ```

But same script run fines when I run it manually. Script has been scheduled with admin user & admin user have access to both server.

```
robocopy /XC /E /R:2 /W:2 /copy:DATS /NDL /NP \\Server\c$\ProgramData\DStt C:\ProgramData\DStt > "D:\Apps\DStt\syncDStt_AppData_Server.log"
```

Comment: What user account is the task running as?  I would add `echo Current User:%UserDomain%\%UserName% >> "D:\Apps\DStt\syncDStt_AppData_Server.log"` after the robocopy line to be sure.

Comment: I am using admin account. Both server having admin account. Is this how you want me to use it.  robocopy echo Current User:%UserDomain%\%UserName% /XC /E /R:2 /W:2 /copy:DATS /NDL /NP \\Server\c$\ProgramData\DStt C:\ProgramData\DStt > "D:\Apps\DStt\syncDStt_AppData_Server.log"

Comment: No, first the robocopy line (just like you have it), then the line will be the one I gave you.  I suspect that you aren't running as the user that you think you are and this will tell us for sure who is running your batch file.